# Choosing a letter from the alphabet and putting quotation marks on it

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program where it asks for a letter from the alphabet. Lets say I choose the letter "b". The "b" should be shown in quotation marks in the program. I'm trying to learn Java, I know HTML and CSS, but Java is new to me, so go easy.

So in practice:

```
Choose a letter:
d
abc"d"efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

I've figured out how to print the alphabet

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Characters {
public static void main(String[] args) {

char c;

for(c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c)
    System.out.print(c + " ");

}
}
```

(I have added scanner, because I'll ask the user for the letter)

Comment: where do you ask for the user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very concise example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        char c = s.next().charAt(0);
        for(char i = 'a'; i < 'z'; i++){
            System.out.print(i == c ? "\""+c+"\"" : i);
        }
    }
}
```

Use `java.util.Scanner`'s `.next()` to read the next word, then get the first character of the word.

Sample Run:

```
a
"a"bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java recognises quotation marks for text, you need to add a \ before each caracter to indicate to java that you wish for it to be part of the text. For example, if you want to show "b" with quotation mark, your final string is going to be a\"b\"cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Answer (score 0):

First, we would have to read the input char:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
char c = scanner.next().charAt(0); // Get char
```

Then, I would make sure that our char is in the alphabet:

```
if(!('a' <= c && c <='z')) {
    return; // NOT IN ALPHABET
}
```

If we got this far, we successfully read a character, which is in the alphabet.
Now, we can print out the modified alphabet.

```
for(char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
    if(letter == c) {
        System.out.print("\"" + c + "\"");
    }else {
        System.out.print(letter);
    }
}
```